# Why we shouldn't use the primitive's boxed type version?

Tags: typescript

Typescript manual mentions that we almost always must use the primitive types, but doesn't explain the reason behind it:

> It can be tempting to think that the types Number, String, Boolean,
> Symbol, or Object are the same as the lowercase versions recommended
> above. These types do not refer to the language primitives however,
> and almost never should be used as a type.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#about-number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object

If we shouldn't use them, then why are they even exist?

Can you elaborate it please?